# regex to grab temperature from string

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a string like the following:

```
blabla world 2 temp 3*C
```

I want to grab only the 3*C part. so the regex must delete everything else. I have a replace function that is supposed to should delete everything else apart from the regex pattern (which in this case only keep 3*C and deletes everything else form the string)

Edit:

Groovy code:

```
if(contains(activity, "*C")){
    replace(activity,"[^\\d.](\\*C)","",true)
}
```

but this replaces that match with "". I want to grab the match only instead.

Edit 2:

Regex must work for decimal numbers as well. For instance: 3.5*C

Comment: Please share the code you are using for it. Also, if you need to extract something, why not use a matching approach?

Comment: see Edit. Thanks

Comment: See [this Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/v7Voiv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a matching approach:

```
String s = "blabla world 2 temp 3*C"
def m = s =~ /\b\d*\.?\d+\*C\b/
println(m[0])
```

See the [Groovy demo](http://ideone.com/v7Voiv)

If the whole part cannot be absent, use

```
def m = s =~ /\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\*C\b/
```

**Details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?`  - an optional dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\*` - an asterisk
- `C` - `C`
- `\b` - trailing word boundary

The `(?:\.\d+)?` in the alternative approach matches 1 or 0 occurrences (due to the `?` quantifier at the end) of a `.` followed with 1+ digits.

Comment: @MaxZoom: That is a wrong value from my point of view as the `34.` is an end of a sentence. `34*C`, `34.5*C`, and `.5*C` look valid to me.

Comment: Right it matches, but it should NOT match